# How can I search data from firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing my project.
My project is App for finding room in my campus.
In my database there are room name, floor, building room and location.

I want to find all records that have a keyword that the user want to find.
And show data about that room.

My firebase

[image]

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link for complete code
http://www.amalhichri.net/android-firebase-realtime-database-basic-cruds/

private void findperson(String name){
     Query deleteQuery = myDatabaseReference.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo(name);

```
    deleteQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Iterable snapshotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            Iterator iterator = snapshotIterator.iterator();
            while((iterator.hasNext())){
                Log.d("Item found: ",iterator.next().getValue().toString()+"---");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }`enter code here`

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Item not found: ","this item is not in the list");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your firebase url to 
"`YourFireBaseUrl/room/cb1201"` to get the data of room no cb1201
you will get the data in `JSON` format